# Load text file as strings using numpy.loadtxt()

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to load a big text file (around 1 GB with 3*10^6 rows and 10 - 100 columns) as a 2D np-array containing strings. However, it seems like numpy.loadtxt() only takes floats as default. Is it possible to specify another data type for the entire array? I've tried the following without luck:

```
loadedData = np.loadtxt(address, dtype=np.str)
```

I get the following error message:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_20224ea_20121123-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin)
    833             fh.close()
    834
--> 835     X = np.array(X, dtype)
    836     # Multicolumn data are returned with shape (1, N, M), i.e.
    837     # (1, 1, M) for a single row - remove the singleton dimension there

ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence
```

Any ideas? (I don't know the exact number of columns in my file on beforehand.)

Answer (score 59):

Use [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) instead. It's a much more general method than `loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
print np.genfromtxt('col.txt',dtype='str')
```

Using the file `col.txt`:

```
foo bar
cat dog
man wine
```

This gives:

```
[['foo' 'bar']
 ['cat' 'dog']
 ['man' 'wine']]
```

If you expect that each row has the same number of columns, read the first row and set the attribute `filling_values` to fix any missing rows.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine, except it's extremely time consuming. But from what I've read, that is expected using `genfromtxt` instead of `loadtxt`. Any way to speed things up? Or any other faster way to load big quantities of data?

Comment: If you are going to be using the dataset again and again you might want to think of a storage solution other than a raw text file. Personally I'd go with pytables or another hd5f solution.

Comment: Actually, python crashes when trying to load a 800Mb text file. It fills up the memory using 8GB RAM and 35GB Swap..

Comment: I use the data to train a classifier algorithm, so I only need it once.

Comment: How to load the string in lower case? Is it possible or I have to convert to lower after loading the file?

Comment: @Sigur you'll have to do that after you load the file. If you want to use `pandas` as indicated in some of the other answers, they have direct string methods for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 17):

There is also [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) in [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29), which is fast and supports non-comma column separators and automatic typing by column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file',sep='\t')
```

It can be converted to a NumPy array if you prefer that type with:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(df)
```

This is by far the easiest and most mature text import approach I've come across.

Answer (score 3):

`np.loadtxt(file_path, dtype=str)`
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is it essential that you need a NumPy array? Otherwise you could speed things up by loading the data as a nested list.

```
def load(fname):
    ''' Load the file using std open'''
    f = open(fname,'r')

    data = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        data.append(line.replace('\n','').split(' '))

    f.close()

    return data
```

For a text file with 4000x4000 words this is about 10 times faster than `loadtxt`.

Comment: if you convert the list obj to ndarray when return it, the time consumption will be almost the same

Comment: Of course in that case you don't save time. That's what I said with the first sentence followed by the *Otherwise* :)