# Numpy has no attribute loadtxt?

Tags: python, numpy, python-import

For the code below:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.loadtxt('ex21_votes.csv', delimiter=",")
```

I get an error: `module 'numpy' has no attribute 'loadtxt'.`

Installed numpy today, here is the output:

```
git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git numpy
Cloning into 'numpy'...
remote: Counting objects: 137888, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Total 137888 (delta 13), reused 19 (delta 10), pack-reused 137854
Receiving objects: 100% (137888/137888), 57.00 MiB | 1.18 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (109223/109223), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Comment: Please show us the output of `np.__file__`. It looks like the `numpy` module you are loading is either too old, or not the real numpy, but another file named `numpy.py`, as [`loadtxt` has been in numpy for a long time](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: You may need to update numpy. On Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install python-numpy

Comment: Any specific reason to compile Numpy? Otherwise I would suggest to install via pip or a package manager.

Comment: There is definitely a `loadtxt` in the current master: [npyio.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/59bd9ee273f26f335f1f77e0b85ede8d209a7e07/numpy/lib/npyio.py). Please show/check the output of `np.__file__` to verify that what you are loading is indeed your compiled version.

Comment: Did you just clone the numpy repo or did you follow [all the instructions](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/INSTALL.rst.txt)?

Comment: Do you have script of your own called `numpy.py`?

Answer (score -3):

Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14985402/8265515) is showing you can use genfromtxt instead. It's a more general method than loadtxt:

`import numpy as np
 print np.genfromtxt('col.txt',dtype='str')`

Using the file col.txt:

`foo bar
 cat dog
 man wine`

This gives:

`[['foo' 'bar']
 ['cat' 'dog']
 ['man' 'wine']]`

If you expect that each row has the same number of columns, read the first row and set the attribute filling_values to fix any missing rows.

Comment: This really does not solve the problem that OP's `numpy` module is missing a method which [should be there](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: @IonicSolutions I know that, but I suggested this as an alternative, as other answers said that this is a more general method.

Comment: That's true, but it's not an answer to OP's question. There is clearly something wrong/inconsistent with their `numpy`.

Comment: If the module the OP imported doesn't  have `loadtxt` it probably won't have `genfromtxt`.